# Synchronizing NSMutableData troubles

Tags: objective-c, core-foundation

We have an NSMutableData object that frequently has data appended to it.  We also frequently pull out data via the `bytes` method for reading.

We've synchronized access to this NSMutableData object via a pthread mutex:

```
pthread_mutex_t _mutex;

pthread_mutexattr_t attributes;
pthread_mutexattr_settype( &attributes, PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT );
pthread_mutex_init( &_mutex, &attributes );
```

and then every time we access this object we:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&_mutex);
const UInt8* rawData = [_coverage bytes];
//code that works with the raw bytes
pthread_mutex_unlock(&_mutex);
```

Also, every `addData` method we have locks the mutex before adding data to the NSMutableData object.

The problem is we still get the occasional `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` while working with `rawData`.  I understand that NSMutableBytes will grow its byte array as data gets added to it.  I also understand that I shouldn't expect `rawData` to magically grow also.

I'm just wondering how we can ever get into this situation where `rawData` has been free'd from underneath us when we have explicitly locked access for both read and write?

Are we doing something wrong with the mutex or the way we are accessing the bytes?

**EDIT**

I discovered the real reason why I was getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  I was not initializing the mutex attributes, so locking the mutex did nothing.  Here is the corrected code:

```
pthread_mutex_t _mutex;

pthread_mutexattr_t attributes;
pthread_mutexattr_init(&attributes);
pthread_mutex_init(&_mutex, &attributes);
pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&attributes);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible that is being freed from underneath you.

According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSData):

> **bytes**
>   *Returns a pointer to the receiver’s contents.*

You should make copies of the data to ensure that it will not be changed or freed from underneath you. When your done with your copy make sure to `free()` it.

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&_mutex);
const UInt8 *origData = [_coverage bytes];
UInt8 *rawData;
memmove(rawData, origData, [_coverage length]);

//code that works with the raw bytes
free(rawData);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&_mutex);
```

Comment: Is it better to just access the bytes via the public apis every time or is it better to just manage our own byte array?

Comment: It really depends on how it is being used because the NSMutableData makes it a lot easier to append data. As you said it seems odd that the mutex did not work by itself, but if there is somewhere outside of that exact mutex changing the data that could be the issue. You did not post your append operation, double check that and make sure it is locking correctly.